# Java Script. Insert data to database by clicking button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I need simple thing, insert data to database by clicking button, but I can't do It successfully.

This is button.php

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return display()">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name22" placeholder="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"><br>

<div id="answer22" class="answer"></div>
```

This is function which get word which user enter and I need to write It to database.

```
function display(){
var i;
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();
    for (i=1;i<=30;i++) {
      if(i==n) {
 var ans    =   document.getElementById("name"+ i).value
 document.getElementById("answer"+ i).innerHTML="Jūsų atsakymas: "+ans.bold();
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(),
url = 'button_sql.php?answer=' + encodeURIComponent(ans);
ajax.open("GET", url, true);
ajax.send();
    }
    }
return false;
}
```

This is my db.php I don't know how to use It correctly.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $name = John; 
    $answer= $_SESSION['answer22']; // I've tried this but unsuccessful
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","asd","asd","asd");


if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into myTable (answer, userName) VALUE (?,?) ")) {
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
//    printf(" ", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}


$stmt->bind_param('ss', $answer, $name);

   $stmt->execute();

   if ($stmt->error != '') {
       echo ' error:'.$stmt->error;
   } else {
       echo 'success';
   }
   $stmt->close();
} else {
   echo 'error:'.$mysqli->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I've tried use this, but useless:

`<form method="post" action="button_sql.php" onsubmit="return display()">`

So someone could help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which aspect of this process is failing? Are you getting any errors? More info will get you more answers

Comment: No errors, just nothing happens. But part of db.php is good, as you see `$name = John;` if I use `http://website/db.php` I got "success" and It write to database userName `John` and answer `NULL`

Comment: Just I can't make It worked by clicking button. I don't get any errors, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you use `return false` in an event listener added using old model, it prevents the default action.

In your case, your event listener `display` prevents the default action of the form (being submitted) because of `return false`.

If you want to submit the form without reloading the page, you should use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) instead.

For example, use something like this:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = 'button_sql.php?answer' + i +'=' + encodeURIComponent(ans);
ajax.open("GET", url, true);
ajax.send();
```

You may want to use `onreadystatechange` too.

And in `db.php`:

```
$answer = $_GET['answer22'];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, this worked, but now reloading page. And where answer in database insert "NULL" so something wrong with code, how to $GET var correctly?

Comment: And how can I get this var in db.php?

Comment: I've used this `var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = 'db.php?anwer22=' + encodeURIComponent(ans);
ajax.open("GET", url, true);
ajax.send();` in `display()` function, and this `$answer = $_GET['answer22'];` in db.php but still I got NULL value in answer (It is INT type in database, maybe here is problem? But I'm trying to insert 100 value, but unsuccessful)

Comment: I found mistake, that because `url = 'db.php?anwer22='` should be `answer22` :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Should be a `post` request, not `get` to remain consistent with the form method

Comment: 1 more question how to use variable (var i;) correctly? In this place where is `answer+i`? in this line `url = 'button_sql.php?answer+i=' + encodeURIComponent(ans);`

Comment: I asked that because here are many answers, I just said "answer22" like example, my i variable always changing so It can be `answer1`, `answer2` etc.

Comment: Maybe something like this: `url = 'button_sql.php?answer'".i."'=' + encodeURIComponent(ans);` ?

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė Use `'button_sql.php?answer' + i +'=' + encodeURIComponent(ans)`

Answer (score 0):

Returning `false` in your `display` function will cause the form to not submit, you should return true instead if you want the form to actually submit

Comment: This will work, but it will load the new page. It won't display the message.

Comment: Thank you for answer, this worked, but now reloading page. And where answer in database insert "NULL" so something wrong with code, how to $GET var correctly?

Comment: You need to use `$_POST`, not `$_GET`

Comment: @jrConway You are correct, but the question was not about the message displaying, it was about the form submitting.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I posted the comment in assumption that the op wanted to make it work without reloading the page, which is only possible with AJAX.